# What test to use to compare observed and expected frequencies when expected frequencies for each subject are independent from each other?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, expected-value

I conducted a study where I presented subjects with a treatment that they could either respond to with a match or non-match. I will use whales as an example. Whales can breach the water in several ways, just the tail, blowhole, head etc. However, in this example each whale prefers to breach the water in different ways. For example, whale 1 breaches with his tail 75% of the time, blowhole 10% of the time etc. Whale two breaches with his head 60% of the time, tail 30 % of the time etc.

I'm interested in seeing whether the whales will respond to a simulated whale breach with the same whale breach (e.g. if I simulate a tail breach the whale does a tail breach). However, since breaches happen at different probabilities for each whale I'm under the impression that my expected value should be the proportion that they naturally do the breach that I'm showing them. So if I show whale 1 from above a tail breach I expect that there is a 75% chance it will tail breach regardless. I simulate multiple tail breaches over a certain amount of time and record the whale's breaching behaviour. I then multiply the expected proportion of tail breaches (0.75) by the number of responses (e.g. 10) and get 7.5 as my expected value. I then do this for every other whale using their specific proportions as they relate to the breach I showed them (sometimes tail, sometimes head etc.). Some whales did not breach in response however showed interest in the stimuli in other ways e.g. came close to the simulated breach. These whales have an expected value of 0 but I don't know if it's appropriate to throw these data out considering they were aware of the stimulus and had the opportunity to match the breach.

I have data that look like this:

```
Obs     Exp
1       1.1
0       0
0       0.08
0       0.44
0       0
0       0.63
23      2.38
0       0.17
0       0.45
3       0.4
0       0
0       0
0       0.33
```

Observed is the number of matching breaches during the treatment. I want to know if the whales matched the breach more often than expected by chance. After helpful comments below, it seems a chi-square test is not appropriate here. What test would be appropriate here? Fisher Exact?

Comment: This is not how a chi-squared test is conducted: it's based on the actual counts, not the proportions.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my data to counts but I still have what seems to me the wrong number of degrees of freedom (for my dataset with 13 columns and 2 rows my DF is 27). I was doing a bit of reading and it seems like a Fisher exact test might be more appropriate considering I don't have a huge sample size and my expected counts are all fairly low (under 5).

Comment: This sounds like you might not be using the software correctly.  You will need to provide details if you would like us to understand your question.

Comment: Alright I added my actual data as well as my code for the test and the results I get.

Comment: The expected frequencies don't have to be integers but they have to have the same sum (namely 27) as the observed. Further, zero expected frequencies are fatal to summing (observed $-$ expected)$^2$ / expected. That said, I don't understand your set-up at all. If there's a structure of different subjects acting repeatedly you may need some quite different analysis.

Comment: For my expected, each subject has a different number of responses to choose from, e.g. subject one has 10 possible responses with 1 match, subject 2 has 15 with one match. Additionally they use each response unequally outside of treatments, e.g. when observing subject 1 it will use response 1 30% of the time, response 2 10% of the time and the "match response" 5% of the time. Subject 2 would have different percentages. To calculate expected I measured the proportion that they use the match response outside of treatments and multiplied it by the number of responses given during the treatment.

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be a binary variable for the observed i.e. match/non-match and the expected would be the inverse of the number of possible responses for each subject?

Comment: I have put this on hold pending clarification of the obvious discrepancy between the data, the description of what is being done, and the output of the software: it's not possible to guess what you are calculating when all three contradict one another.  Perhaps the most constructive way forward is to respond to the suggestions made by @NickCox.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you want me to do. I updated my question to include my data, I described what I did (a chi-square test) and gave the output that R gave me. I then ask if a Fisher exact test may be more appropriate for my data instead. I'll add a quick line mentioning that maybe a completely different test may be appropriate. II want to calculate if the observed differs from the expected. I know stats is a weak point for me so I'm here trying to get help.

Comment: I am only a very occasional R user, but with `obs` and `exp` 12 x 1 vectors as above `table(obs, exp)` shows  a 4 x 9 contingency table for rows which are the distinct values of `obs` and the columns which are the distinct values of `exp`. That translation of the problem makes no sense to me as a comparison of observed and expected  frequencies, but I can't even reproduce the chi-square result which R yields as $X^2$ = 36 on 24 df. Sorry, but I don't think that you have in any sense explained why expected frequencies have a different total or why (0, 0) pairs belong in the calculation.

Comment: Nobody is trying to pull rank on you statistically: the problem is that no-one can make any sense at all of what you are doing, beyond pointing out choices that make no sense.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out Nick and whuber. Let me try to explain my expected values again. My subjects each have between 8-16 responses or so they can use in response to the treatment. They use these responses in day to day life but they also use them in response to treatments. In day-to-day life, they use certain responses preferentially over others. I am presenting them with a stimulus that matches one of those responses. Since they don't use those responses equally in day to day life I thought a better exp would be the proportion they use it i.e. the chance that it occurs naturally.

Comment: I missed a row when putting the data in, I'll fix it now

Comment: The more you explain this, the less it seems like a chi-square problem at all. You have observed and expected values of some kind -- I don't know what they are. I still don't understand whether you have 13 subjects or fewer. But even the briefest of comparisons suggests that  observed and expected are quite different. If you want statistical advice, please don't abstract, make concrete. Phrases like "day-to-day life" don't make anything precise or clear. 23 for example means 23 what? What is being counted? Also, if subjects vary in how they might respond, in what senses are they comparable?

Comment: The question about df increasing when expected frequencies of zero occur now seems resolved as an illusion caused by pushing your data through `table()` inappropriately. But I'm still far from suggesting an appropriate analysis.

Comment: Most people use chi-square tests in this field so I thought I should use one. 23 is 23 matching responses. The observed are the number of responses that matched the stimulus. Day-to-day life as in each animal uses these responses outside of the context of the treatment. For example if a whale breaches the water it may just put up its tail, just its blowhole etc. In this example I'd be presenting a whale with a tail breach and then observing if it also breaches its tail or breaches something else or doesn't breach altogether.

Comment: That's a little clearer to me. My conclusion -- it's late where I am, which is my reason for stopping at this point -- is  that you have a table of data that you can discuss and perhaps even plot. Chi-square tests make no sense, however, for your particular table. I am sure that people in your field use them for other data, but these don't fit the framework at all. .

Comment: @whuber I changed the question to ask instead what test I should be using. I hope that my example and write-up makes it more clear. Thank you to you and Nick for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would stop thinking about this as a chi-square problem or one involving observed and expected in this way.

First, let me try to summarize your problem. You think that the type of breach that the whale sees affects the type of breach they perform. Each whale may have different patterns of responses and each whale is shown multiple breaches.

If that is correct, then this seems like a regression problem with dependent errors and one solution would be to use a multilevel model and, since the response variable is a count, probably you need a nonlinear MLM.  In R, look into the nlme package.